# Count Occurence of Needle String in Haystack String, most optimally?

Tags: java, algorithm

The Problem is simple Find "ABC" in "ABCDSGDABCSAGAABCCCCAAABAABC" without using String.split("ABC")

Here is the solution I propose, I'm looking for any solutions that might be better than this one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 String haystack = "ABCDSGDABCSAGAABCCCCAAABAABC";
 String needle = "ABC";
 char [] needl = needle.toCharArray();
 int needleLen = needle.length();
 int found=0;
 char hay[] = haystack.toCharArray();
 int index =0;
 int chMatched =0;

 for (int i=0; i<hay.length; i++){

  if (index >= needleLen || chMatched==0)
   index=0;
  System.out.print("\nchar-->"+hay[i] + ", with->"+needl[index]);

  if(hay[i] == needl[index]){
   chMatched++;
   System.out.println(", matched");
  }else {
   chMatched=0;
   index=0;
   if(hay[i] == needl[index]){
    chMatched++;
    System.out.print("\nchar->"+hay[i] + ", with->"+needl[index]);
    System.out.print(", matched");
   }else
   continue;
  }

  if(chMatched == needleLen){
   found++;
   System.out.println("found. Total ->"+found);
  }
  index++;
 } 
 System.out.println("Result Found-->"+found);
 }
```

It took me a while creating this one. Can someone suggest a better solution (if any)
P.S. Drop the sysouts if they look messy to you.

Comment: Be so kind as to indent every line of code with four spaces, that will make it more readable and add syntax highlighting.
P.S.: If it's some kind of homework, add it as a tag ;)

Comment: "Better" and "optimally" in terms of what? Memory footprint? Speed? Maintainability?

Comment: Performance, and performance. Memory is not an issue.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
boolean found = haystack.indexOf("ABC") >= 0;
```

**Edit - The question asks for number of occurences, so here's a modified version of the above:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String needle = "ABC";
    String haystack = "ABCDSGDABCSAGAABCCCCAAABAABC";

    int numberOfOccurences = 0;
    int index = haystack.indexOf(needle);
    while (index != -1)
    {
        numberOfOccurences++;
        haystack = haystack.substring(index+needle.length());
        index = haystack.indexOf(needle);
    }

    System.out.println("" + numberOfOccurences);
}
```

Comment: Should be done iteratively, each time starting at 1 beyond the last found pos (or "ABC".length() beyond index) to count the amount of occurrences (which is the question).

Comment: nah, that only says yes or no. I asked for count. and yes don't use String.Split("ABC")

Comment: OK, that wasn't particularly clear from your question which simply asked to find the string "ABC" in a longer string.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for an *algorithm*, google for "Boyer-Moore".  You can do this in sub-linear time.

**edit** to clarify and hopefully make all the purists happy: the time bound on Boyer-Moore is, formally speaking, linear.  However the effective performance is often such that you do many fewer comparisons than you would with a simpler approach, and in particular you can often skip through the "haystack" string without having to check each character.

Comment: Boyer-Moore is O(N), i.e. linear.

Comment: Well when you do it right, you can skip through the text (the "haystack", in terms of this question) such that you don't have to look at every character. It depends on the search string, of course; if the search string is one character long, then it's always just linear. And yes, formally the worst-case performance is linear (I think it's 3n right?)

Comment: Nice article on wikipedia about this!

Comment: @Pointy Of course, but that does not change the fact that it is linear. Complexity analysis does not care about constants, so it's O(N). There is no general guarantee that Boyer-Moore will be faster than a naive approach, it all depends on the string being searched.

Comment: @Havard complexity analysis may not care about constants, but people who need the performance do. Even if you don't get a guarantee it's faster you at least get a chance.

Comment: @Pointy: even with skipping, it is still O(N) and lineair time, the constant is only smaller than with a more naive search method.

Comment: Fine. However, if you're ever working for **me**, and you pick an algorithm with a bigger constant performance factor than another, well, you won't be working for me for much longer.

Comment: @extraneon The question asks for a generally "fast" solution, and it is important to understand that there is no such thing. You need to analyze your data; applying Boyer-Moore because it "may be faster" is not a smart thing to do.

Comment: The naive method is theta(N), where as Boyer-Moore is O(N).

Comment: @Pointy Although I agree with you when performance is critical I could just as easily pick a suboptimal but easier/trivial to understand solution in other cases where development time and maintenance complexity are more limited. So I'm afraid I don't get to work at your place then :)

Comment: @extraneon naah I'm much nicer than that :-)  This whole discussion is pretty silly given that the original question is probably from an "Intro to Algorithms" class, and all these fine points of performance analysis are waaay more sophisticated.

Answer (score 1):

You say your challenge is to find ABC within a string. If all you need is to know if ABC exists within the string, a simple `indexOf()` test will suffice.

If you need to know the number of occurrences, as your posted code tries to find, a simple approach would be to use a regex:

```
public static int countOccurrences(string haystack, string regexToFind) {
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexToFind);
   Matcher m = p.matcher(haystack); // get a matcher object
   int count = 0;
   while(m.find()) {
       count++;
   }
   return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Havard, RegEx is a good option but I'm only interested in learning the "Best algorithm" that consumes least CPU time

Comment: Like I've stated in two comments, that all depends on the string you're searching in. There is no general "best algorithm" answer, sadly. Prefer the simple solution, premature optimization is the root of all evil. (Knuth)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

```
public class NeedleCount
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String s="AVBVDABCHJHDFABCJKHKHF",ned="ABC";
    int nedIndex=-1,count=0,totalNed=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
      if(i>ned.length()-1)
        nedIndex++;
      else
        nedIndex=i;
      if(s.charAt(i)==ned.charAt(nedIndex))
        count++;
      else
      {
        nedIndex=0;
        count=0;
         if(s.charAt(i)==ned.charAt(nedIndex))
          count++;
        else
          nedIndex=-1;
      }
      if(count==ned.length())
      {
        nedIndex=-1;
        count=0;
        totalNed++;
        System.out.println(totalNed+" needle found at index="+(i-(ned.length()-1)));
      }
    }
    System.out.print("Total Ned="+totalNed);
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Asked by others, better in what sense? A regexp based solution will be the most concise and readable (:-) ). Boyer-Moore (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer–Moore_string_search_algorithm) will be the most efficient in terms of time (O(N)).

Comment: Again, there is no guarantee that Boyer-Moore will be more efficient than a naive search (it depends on the string being searched).

Comment: Also consider Horspool's variation which is simpler to implement: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore-Horspool_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind implementing a new datastructure as replacement for strings, have a look at Tries: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringTrie or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

If you don't look for a regular expression but an exact match they should provide the fastest solution (proportional to length of search string).

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class FindNeedleInHaystack {

        String hayStack="ASDVKDBGKBCDGFLBJADLBCNFVKVBCDXKBXCVJXBCVKFALDKBJAFFXBCD";
        String needle="BCD";
        boolean flag=false;

        public void findNeedle() {
//Below for loop iterates the string by each character till reaches max length
            for(int i=0;i<hayStack.length();i++) {  
//When i=n (0,1,2... ) then we are at nth character of hayStack. Let's start comparing nth char of hayStach with first char of needle
                if(hayStack.charAt(i)==needle.charAt(0)) {
//if condition return true, we reach forloop which iterates needle by lenghth.
//Now needle(BCD) first char is 'B' and nth char of hayStack is 'B'. Then let's compare remaining characters of needle with haystack using below loop. 
                    for(int j=0;j<needle.length();j++) {
//for example at i=9 is 'B', i+j is i+0,i+1,i+2...
//if condition return true, loop continues or else it will break and goes to i+1
                        if(hayStack.charAt(i+j)==needle.charAt(j)) {
                            flag=true;
                        } else {
                            flag=false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(flag) {
                        System.out.print(i+" ");
                    }
                }                               
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hope this helps for any needle, you can change the hayStack and try with different needle

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will perform exactly O(n) complexity because we are looping n chars of haystack. If you want to capture start and end index's of needle uncomment below commented code. Solution is around playing with characters and no Java String functions (Pattern matching, IndexOf, substring etc.,) are used as they may bring extra space/time complexity

```
        char[] needleArray = needle.toCharArray();
        char[] hayStackArray = hayStack.toCharArray();
        //java.util.LinkedList<Pair<Integer,Integer>> indexList = new LinkedList<>();

        int head;
        int tail = 0;
        int needleCount = 0;

        while(tail<hayStackArray.length){

            head = tail;
            boolean proceed = false;
            for(int j=0;j<needleArray.length;j++){
                if(head+j<hayStackArray.length && hayStackArray[head+j]==needleArray[j]){
                    tail = head+j;
                    proceed = true;
                }else{
                    proceed = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(proceed){
               // indexList.add(new Pair<>(head,tail));
                needleCount++;
            }
            ++tail;
        }

        System.out.println(needleCount);
        //System.out.println(indexList);
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue